# Using XAMPP PHP to read external url

Tags: php, xampp

I have PHP on XAMPP working fine.

Without using FTP, and the example if this was simple MS-DOS, I wish to achieve the following:

> copy https://www.externalurl.com/12345.pdf localfile1.pdf
>
> copy https://www.externalurl.com/directory/45asf.pdf localfile2.pdf
>
> copy https://www.externalurl.com/fred.pdf localfile3.pdf
>
> copy https://www.externalurl.com/a/y/f/1.pdf localfile4.pdf

This process will achieve the local renaming of some two thousand PDFs which exist on a website and whose full urls are held in a database, to sensible names in a single directory. Nearly all of the original files are in different and random directories but all are on the same website.

Once this is done, we'll ftp up the new directory with the new names to the website and job done.

`file_get_contents($url)` and then write the local file would work perfectly but, being new to XAMPP, ports and proxies, I realise that my XAMPP setup will not read anything external to the local machine at this point.

How could I achieve `file_get_contents("https://www.externalurl.com/fred.pdf")` successfully?

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried and the errors you have, this helps in working out where the problem is and helps sorting it out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is a random PDF on the web within my code:

<pre>
<?php
echo "here<br>";
$url  = 'https://earth.esa.int/documents/10174/1514862/Swarm_L2_Product_Specification';
$path = 'output.pdf';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents($path, $data);
echo filesize ( $path);

?>
</pre>

Here's the result of this code:

<pre>
here
0 
</pre>

Comment: Sorry for the gobbledigook just there - clearer below...

Comment: Surely somebody voting this question down demotes it to invisibility? I need to find a solution; why did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php script to download remote file and name it whatever you want, If files are more then one, you can do this in loop.

```
$url  = 'https://www.externalurl.com/12345.pdf';

$path = '/path/to/localfile1.pdf';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

Comment: Sorry my comment ended up as its own answer - new to stackexchange!